# What utility can move my Windows boot partition over to another hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, backup, partitioning

Can anyone recommend a cheap/free utility that can do this without very much effort?

My preference is that it would be really easy.

- Boot into Windows
- Pick drive to move
- Pick target drive
- It copies everything over, and reboots to the correct partition.

Comment: if they're the same size, you could use a linux live cd and use dd .. http://superuser.com/questions/11453/how-to-move-from-one-drive-to-another-thats-a-different-size was a question i asked on linux drives

Comment: Many tools on this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison%5Fof%5Fdisk%5Fcloning%5Fsoftware) from wikipedia support NTFS.

Comment: Use a LiveCD with Gparted. It works on both 32 and 64 bit systems. See my answer for details.

Comment: spent an hour trying to find this question from the `[backup]` tag (perhaps would be more useful than one of `[operating-systems]`, `[hard-drive]` or `[partitioning]`)

Comment: Intel Data Migration

Comment: I know this is old but this question belongs on [SR](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

### DriveImage XML

[DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) will do the job.  It runs from within Windows and it can copy directly from drive to drive.  A lot of people rave about it after good experiences with the software.

[image]

> DriveImage XML is an easy to use and reliable program for imaging and backing up partitions and logical drives.
>
> Image creation uses Microsoft's Volume Shadow Services (VSS), allowing you to create safe "hot images" even from drives currently in use. Images are stored in XML files, allowing you to process them with 3rd party tools. Never again be stuck with a useless backup! Restore images to drives without having to reboot. DriveImage XML is now faster than ever, offering two different compression levels.

---

### EASEUS Disk Copy

[EASEUS Disk Copy](http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/) is a great alternative if you don't want to go for a 'hot' backup that runs from within Windows.  Good review at [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/400615/easeus-disk-copy-makes-a-fast-clone-of-your-hard-drive) and on a par with DriveImage XML.  They quite clearly state that it is ideal for moving from one disk to a larger one.  Like other suggestions, this requires that you create a boot CD.

> EASEUS Disk Copy is a potent freeware
> providing sector-by-sector
> disk/partition clone regardless of
> your operating system, file systems
> and partition scheme by creating a
> bootable CD. The sector-by-sector
> method assures you a copy 100%
> identical to the original. Disk Copy
> can be used for copy, cloning, or
> upgrading your original small hard
> drive to a new larger drive. Simply
> speaking, it can copy anything from
> the old hard drive including the
> deleted, lost files and inaccessible
> data. So, the freeware is a perfect
> tool for Data Recovery Wizard to
> recover files from a backup disk.

Comment: Have you personally used it more than once with great success? As in there are no gotchas?

Comment: Create an empty partition on your new disk first, ready to copy the image into. No need to format it. Once copied, set the drive to 'active' in Disk Management (Start | Run | diskmgmt.msc) and either change the boot disk in the BIOS or shutdown and physically swap the disks over. All in the FAQ on the website. We used this method to move XP onto a bigger disk, worked a treat.

Comment: +1 for DriveImage XML. I took a system with 2 x 20GB physical drives and cloned them onto one partitioned 80GB drive, and three years later, the customer is still up and running without a format.

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong as DriveImage is very simple, but when I tried to boot off the cloned drive it wouldn't boot.

Comment: I tried using DriveImage to clone my OS drive, but it didn't work for me. 'Copying xxx failed' 'Unable to retrieve drive layout'.

Comment: DriveImage XML internally uses the same backup / restore Windows uses, and inherits its quirks, but is way easier to use. The Pros have been mentioned, two Cons to consider: (1) DriveImage is relatively slow (2 hrs for one disk, 0.5 hours same disk with, for instance, Macrium Reflect). (2) DriveImage cannot restore to a _Disk_ smaller than the original disk. Mind you: this is not about partition sizes, but about disk sizes (try to restore a backup of a 1TB partition of a 6TB disk to a 1TB partition of a 2TB disk, won't work).

Comment: Comment moved from OP's question: I tried out DriveImage XML running on XP Professional x64 installed on 1TB Drive.
I had two other drives (250 GB & 500 GB) and I needed my 500 GB drive to add to an array that I was adding to my new computer. This 500 GB had a 95 GB partition that I wanted to stick on the 250 GB drive. I really couldn't get the software to run perfect on x64, but it did go through the process.

Comment: Comment moved from OP's question: Well it ended up sticking the 95 GB partition on the 250 GB drive with no extra space and I couldn't resize the partition. I needed to use recovery console to get the crap to boot, and even then the drive letter was set to D and so nothing was working. I did some google and tried some stuff, but I couldn't get regedit to run and so I punted and re-installed Vista from scratch on the 250 GB. Just always make sure you back up your stuff.

Comment: Some notes for Win7 users: Live copy works perfectly, but you have to boot from Win7-DVD/USB afterwards to "repair" the copied hdd [simply press "repair"]. Otherwise your pc will not recognize the copied partition/hdd as bootable.

Comment: Apparently no support for GPT :(

Comment: It does not work in my Windows 7 to copy C:. Gives some read error but Acronis Trueimage copies it successfully.

Comment: didn't work for me, said the target partion _must be same size or bigger_, which not always helpful when you are cloning to an SSD

Comment: I cloned a Windows boot drive with EaseUS, and it worked very well. It was only later that I realized the program had left a lot of crapware on the new drive. It took a bit of work to remove the garbage, so watch out for this.

Comment: Just FYI, I tried to install the free version of EaseUS to see what it could do, and it comes bundled with adware that can't be skipped during install. Beware.

Comment: DriveImage XML is not too impressive.  I tried copying my main SSD drive partition over to an old HDD drive and it gave me a "could not lock destination drive" error.

Answer (score 47):

Although [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org) is quite an underrated allround (offline) non-gui Linux tool (from the creators of PartImage that iirc doesn't support Ext4), I agree that DriveImage XML is the best answer so far. But also try [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html). Next time. ;)

Here's a summary of tools for partition cloning I have used in the past:

- [image: Windows] [image: Online cloning supported!] [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) (Home Edition is free)
- [image: Windows] [image: Online cloning supported!] [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) (free for personal non-commercial use) (Disk To Disk)
- [image: Linux] [image: Offline cloning only] [CloneZilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) (Open Source)
- [image: Linux] [image: Online cloning supported!] [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/) (Online with -A (untested))
- [image: Linux] [image: Offline cloning only] [Ghost 4 Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/) (Open Source)
- [image: Linux] [image: Offline cloning only] [PartClone](http://partclone.org/) (Disk To Disk)
- [image: Linux] [image: Offline cloning only] [PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/) (Open Source) (No Ext4) (Image Required)
- [image: Linux] [image: Offline cloning only] [Mondo Rescue](http://www.mondorescue.org)
- [image: Windows] [image: Online cloning supported!] [XXClone](http://www.xxclone.com/) (Full Shadow Copy) (Skips EFS on NTFS)

([image: Offline cloning only] for offline cloning, [image: Online cloning supported!] for online cloning)

Comment: I just used MiniTool Partition to copy my partition after DriveImage XML failed me. Works fantastic.

Comment: MiniTool's free edition CAN NOT copy SYSTEM partition.

Answer (score 41):

### GParted

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) on the Ubuntu (and I'm sure other Linux distros) Live CD will do exactly this.  I've used it to successfully migrate entire operating systems from one dying drive to another new drive.

> GParted is a free partition editor for graphically managing your disk partitions.
>
> GParted is useful for tasks such as: creating space for new operating systems, restructuring disk space to separate user and operating system data, and **copying partitions** to enable upgrading to a larger hard disk drive.

Comment: If I copy my Windows partition to a new drive will it boot cleanly or do I still have to do something with it?

Comment: At most, you'd need to tell it to fix the mbr and/or boot record which is easily done using recovery mode on the install dvd.  As I remember it (haven't had to migrate os in a while), GParted should take care of that too.

Comment: I tried. I tried both auto recovery and running 'bootrec /fixmbr' + 'bootrec /rebuildbcd' but the second after finding the correct c:\Windows installation returned me "Unable to find the item" ("Impossibile trovare l'elemento")

Answer (score 29):

### Clonezilla

You could try out [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php).

> Clonezilla, based on DRBL, Partclone and udpcast, allows you to do bare metal backup and recovery. Two types of Clonezilla are available, Clonezilla live and Clonezilla SE (server edition). Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine backup and restore.

It doesn't perfectly meet your requirements, but the disk to disk clone instructions are [here](http://www.clonezilla.org/fine-print-live-doc.php?path=./clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone/).

Answer (score 19):

My easiest way is to put in a booting NetBSD or Linux CD, boot, and tell it to

```
dd if=/dev/hda of=/dev/hdb
```

I then shutdown, unplug the first drive, and reboot.  Just as my easiest way may not seem easy to you, I guarantee you that all these other easiest ways don't seem like it to me. The important thing here is:

1. Your system is not running off of the disk you are cloning while you clone it.
2. You get all of the associated data of the boot sector and the partition map.
3. Because both disks remain bootable, you've got to switch them about or remove one in order to get the new disk to boot.

Now granted, this copies only the exact same partition map; if you want something different, you need to ask.

Comment: Assuming this gets your system booting, you can use parted to resize partitions later.  Are there situations where the copied bootloader may fail to work, e.g. different sector sizes?

Comment: There is `dd` for Windows running in console (Command Prompt) mode.

Answer (score 15):

### Acronis TrueImage

I have personally used [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) Home Edition, upgraded that to Home Edition 2009.

> Acronis True Image Home 2011 assures that all your important data, including photos, videos, music, documents and applications, are fully protected and can be recovered quickly in the event of any disaster.

Have NEVER had a failure, never had a gotcha. Now however, as mentioned above, you can get it for FREE by downloading Seagate Disk Wizard, from their website. It's the same as Acronis, but with Seagate's name on in, obviously because they paid a fee for that.

Comment: free if you have at least one seagate disk. else it won't work

Comment: Acronis failed me, whilst clonezilla did not.

Answer (score 7):

Partimage can do it, but it's all command line stuff.
this link should help you with doing that. 
http://www.partimage.org/Partimage-manual_Backup-partition-table

Comment: Not just command-line: there are interactive menus too. But you have to know what you do. I have used successfully.

The [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) is a Linux distribution that includes that tool. It's free.

Answer (score 7):

> My preference is that it would be
>   really easy. Boot into Vista. Pick
>   drive to move, pick target drive,
>   copies everything over, **and reboots
>   to correct partition**.

if you mean the newly cloned drive by "correct partition", then this cannot be done automatically. you'll have to clone the drive and then set it in the BIOS as primary boot device or (if the BIOS doesn't provide this option) connect the drive to the primary controller.

furthermore, you're looking for 'hot imaging' of a 'live operating system' which is not recommended (unless absolutely necessary), too many things can go wrong.

for further reference, you may want to read this:

> [**RADIFIED - Guide to Norton
>   Ghost**](http://ghost.radified.com/) presents what many
>   consider the **ultimate back-up
>   strategy**. It is based on features
>   found in Ghost, a hard drive
>   imaging/cloning software program
>   developed by Symantec. Altho designed
>   around Ghost (considered the most
>   reliable application of its kind), the
>   strategies presented here (such as
>   performing a test-restore, to ensure
>   your back-up image will work when you
>   really need it) **can be applied to
>   any disk cloning program.**. After
>   nearly 9 years on the 'Net - and
>   countless updates - it is still the
>   site's **most requested Windows
>   tutorial**. Users of Ghost from all
>   over the world contribute regularly to
>   the insights it contains, which might
>   be why its popularity continues to
>   grow. When you realize how much time &
>   misery Ghost's supernatural disaster
>   recovery features can save you.

as outlined, many of these practices and tips can applied to other disk cloning programs, in case you have other preferences than Ghost. i will not tell you to which program to use because there are many available that are equally as good (Ghost, Drive Snapshot and DIXML are just very easy to integrate into BartPE) but Radified's is (by a far cry) the best tutorial on drive cloning i have ever come accross. this may not be the 'easiest method' but data security in general and drive cloning in particular is too serious to be taken lightly. even if you get lucky and don't need the backup, you definitely want it to be reliable and ready to be applied at a moments notice (should the faeces ever hit the paddles :).

Answer (score 7):

+1 for GParted.  I needed to migrate XP from a 60G drive to a 320G drive.  Here's what I did:

1. I installed Ubuntu Desktop Edition on a 8G USB Drive (http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download).
2. I put the new drive in an external drive enclosure (this one actually: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817145133)
3. I backed up my old 60G drive. I shut down the PC, then powered up but upon startup entered the BIOS (by hitting F2 in my case).
4. In the BIOS I changed the boot ordering so the the USB drive would have first priority.
5. I saved the BIOS change and allowed the PC to boot into Ubuntu from the USB drive.
6. From a Linux command shell I ran: sudo gparted
7. In gparted I created a single ntfs partition on the new 320G drive.
8. In gparted I navigated to the old 60G drive, clicked on the existing partition, and selected "Copy".
9. In gparted I then navigated to the new 320G drive, clicked on the new partition, and selected "paste".  After asking if I was sure, Gparted proceeded to copy the contents of old drive to new.
10. In gparted I marked the new drive's partition as bootable (from menu: Partition-Manage Flags)
11. I shutdown the PC, took out the old drive, put in the new. (Note: do not attempt to boot with both drives attached - I've read that XP doesn't like that).
12. I powered up and it booted to an XP Chkdsk screen (presumably XP noticed that something about the drive had changed and decided to check it out).  No errors were found and XP then booted up.  Migration done.

Comment: You don't need to *install* Ubuntu to use GParted: you can use `apt-get install gparted` from the LiveCD. But you could also use the [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) that is a Live CD that already has that tool.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com) at the time of writing.

Our software will allow you to take images of disks of all sorts, including Windows boot disks, EFI disks, GPT disks etc. For example, at the time of writing I have broken a VM I've been running (quite badly, the partition type has disappeared!):

[image: Recovery Window]

This is a single disk XP-install; however, we can also restore Windows 7 systems.

I could sit here and and be all marketing-y, but I'm no good at it. Here's how we shape up against your requirements.

- Boot into Windows - Reflect runs from Windows and uses VSS; however, we can also build Windows PE/WAIK based rescue disks including the full software, as such, you have a choice of backup method and recovery. If you need to repair your MBR, we can do that from the boot CD.
- Pick drive to move - Reflect can back up individual drives or whole disks as needed. We support a variety of strategies; we use Volume Shadow Copy Service to image your disk (or fall back to our own driver if needed). The result can be saved to a file, DVD etc.
- pick target drive - Yep. Once you've taken your image, we can write it down to any disk.
- It copies everything over, and reboots to the correct partition. Yes. Depending on your configuration, you may need to choose our "restore | fix boot options" from the recovery disk.

We have a free edition which should be able to do most of what you need - however, we also offer paid-for editions with more advanced features. The [free edition download page](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) offers the usual comparison table.

Comment: Does it support moving Windows to a disk with existing partitions?

Comment: @ak3naton Yes. You'll need enough space for your partitions as you'd expect, and you can shrink/enlarge your partitions as you need to.

Answer (score 4):

Paragon Software's [Drive Backup 9.0 Free Edition](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/db-express/), a very complete backup/restore product.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Seagate drives you can use [Seagate Disk Wizard](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=DiscWizard&vgnextoid=d9fd4a3cdde5c010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD) which is the Acronis True Image licensed to Seagate. I have Seagate drives so I use this a lot and I like it. I'm able to do fairly quick backups and restoring is rather quick too. It's completely free as long as you are using a Seagate drive.

I've used [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/); I use the LiveCD do a backup of my computer and then go ahead and mess around. It's free but the UI can be intimidating as it's pretty much not existant but does a great job. I haven't used it for Vista but I'm sure it can work.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the free [Paragon Drive Backup](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/db-express/) a couple of times with great success.  Basically you plug the new drive in, clone your old hard drive, then replace the old drive with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Cloning a live system in never a good idea, no matter what people say to you. Using shadow copies and other workarounds is never as good as plain old sector-by-sector copy and this is exactly what you want if you would like to clone partitions to another disk. Go for a solution that boots from CD or USB, so that your system is offline.

Others have already mentioned Clonezilla. It is a powerful freeware tool, running from live CD. I'm using it in business environment for a number of years. It is linux based, so it can be a bit confusing if you're not familiar with linux.

I have only second hand knowledge about EASEUS Disk Copy, but I hear it is simple and highly efficient. My first choice is still Clonezilla as it helped me many times, but if Linux is not your thing, go for Disk Copy. And remember, avoid cloning system with Windows running.

Answer (score 2):

Long time Ghost user here. First started using it as a Desktop Support monkey at Duke Medical Center. Never had a problem. You do have to play with it a bit to get your whole methodology down. Even the older versions of Ghost out perform most of the tools available today.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used the free version of [HD Clone](http://www.miray.de/products/sat.hdclone.html) to move to my new hard drive.

It was simple enough, runs from within Windows, no need for Live CD. Does auto-expand to the larger partition.

Not much to tell, actually. It just worked.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OS X I'd use [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/software/ccc.html). The "new" HDD will be bootable and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Load a linux LiveCD (I use Linux Mint 9 because it's a stable long term release).

Open the terminal from the menu.

**Install fsarchiver:**

> sudo apt-get install fsarchiver

If you need to partition the hard drive using gparted

> sudo gparted

**Backup the MBR:**

> dd if=/dev/sda of=/[locationofmbrfile]/backup.mbr bs=512 count=1

/dev/sda refers to the first hard disk, the rest just copies the first 512 bytes (containing the mbr) to a file.

**Back up the filesystem:**

> fsarchiver savefs /[locationtosavebackup]/backup.fsa /dev/sda1

This backs up the first partition on the first hard drive to a file called backup.fsa. If you're trying to backup to an external hard drive, you Mint should auto-mount it under the /media folder. So the path to the external hard drive would be something like /media/[harddrivename]/backup.fsa

---

For the rest of the steps we'll assume that the new hard drive is also attached to the system. Check to see what device the second hard drive is assigned to using gparted (ex sda, sdb, sdc, etc...). We'll assume that it's the second hard disk attached or sdb.

**Copy the MBR over:**

> dd if=/[locationofmbrfile]/backup.mbr of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1

**Copy the partition over:**

> fsarchiver restfs /[locationtosavebackup]/backup.fsa id=0,dest=/dev/sdb1

This is pretty much the reverse of the backup steps except the device changed to sdb because the changes are being applied to the second hard disk.

That's it...

If you're not afraid of the command line, doing backups using linux is a cakewalk. The advantage of using fsarchiver is, it does file-based backups instead of data block backups like clonezilla or partimage. That means that it's possible do a restore on a partition that is smaller than the one that was originally backed up (as long as the data size doesn't exceed the size). That essentially

---

**If you want a GUI-only solution:**

- load the LiveCD
- open the terminal
- sudo gparted
- copy the drive you want to copy
- paste it onto another drive
- hit apply

This is essentially the linux equivalent to the DriveXML mentioned in one of the other answers except it can be run from a cd (ie doesn't require a working system).

Note: If the destination drive is smaller than the source drive you may not be able to do the copy.

Comment: You recommend a Live CD, but the tool you use are not on the CD and require a working network connection to use `apt-get`. It would be simpler to use a Live CD that already has the tools such as the [System Rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page).