# Formatting new hard drive?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, formatting

I just recently bought a brand new laptop.  The hardware was awesome, but the hard drive was...eh (320GB, not my cup of tea).  So I ended up taking Jeff Atwood's [suggestion](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/revisiting-solid-state-hard-drives.html) and bought a hybrid hard drive (500GB, bare drive).

When I received it, I immediately took the old one out and put the new one in and reinstalled Windows 7.  And to my amazement, it was one of the best upgrades I ever did! BUT one thing that still bothers me, I forgot to pre-format the drive....(due to over excitement haha)  I'm usually good at playing it safe, and ensuring I take the extra steps for the health of my laptops.

So my question, is there any repercussions for not formatting a new hard drive and installing a new OS, short-term and long-term?  Should I [clone my newly installed OS](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/easiest-way-to-copy-or-clone-boot-partition-onto-new-hard-drive) (I say clone because I have already put most of my music, videos, and documents back on the new drive also), format the drive, and put the clone back on?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows have formatted your hard drive during installation, in NTFS, as it can't install on a non formatted hard drive.
You'll be able to clone it without problem using any tools Like CloneZilla/SystemRescueCD/(* any other software or Live CD)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

If the drive came pre-formatted to NTFS, then you don't need to do anything else.

The OS installation cleared the boot-loader, so security won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When Windows 7 Installs it pretty much takes care of the formatting for you. Not like Windows XP whre you had to choose (fat, ntfs, or quick) depending on your preference. I wouldn't worry too much about. :)

Danbo