# Cloning a hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, computer-architecture, cloning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clone a Hard Disk Content to Another Hard Disk](https://superuser.com/questions/207083/clone-a-hard-disk-content-to-another-hard-disk)
>   [Bit-for-bit copy of hard drive in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/322804/bit-for-bit-copy-of-hard-drive-in-windows)

There is a hard drive in a laptop. I need to clone it (preferably bit-for-bit) onto another hard drive. Is there any possible way I could do that? w/o installing software on the computer

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a software to clone the the hard drive?

Comment: you can run clonezilla from a bootable cd have you looked at that?

Answer (score 1):

Some drive imaging software, like the [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage) (a commercial product), will allow you to create a bootable CD/DVD that can accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) and [ReDO Backup & Recovery](http://redobackup.org/) have live cds, which can be run without installing software... you can clone directly to another hd or to a file to be restored later. Your new hd must be the same size or bigger.