# Copy contents of data drive with VSS

Tags: windows, hard-drive, backup, gpt, vss

I have a number of GPT data drives (i.e., *not* the boot/OS drive) I want to regularly backup to a external drives.  I haven't found a practical way to do this:

1. I can use a "clone" feature in something like [EaseUS](https://superuser.com/a/322844/297822), but that only works for one-to-one drives.  I want to copy the contents of two data drives onto one backup drive.
2. All "Backup" products I have tried create (often proprietary) archives, preventing individual files from being accessed without extracting (sometimes the entire archive).
3. Using `robocopy` or any other non-VSS utility will invariably get stuck on files that are open.  I don't want to have to shut all programs and services to do a bulk copy of a drive.
4. Any utility that does a file-by-file copy takes days to run.  I can "clone" 1TB of data in under 4 hours, but all methods I have tried (copy, xcopy, robocopy) that try to move files iteratively take at least 24 hours to copy the same data set.

What are practical options for taking copies of data on large working drives under Windows 7 or 10?

Comment: Why not use Windows built-in backup functionality - this utilises VSS?? Do an initial backup and then everything else is incremental. Or have I missed something :S

Comment: @Kinnectus - Because I don't want a backup archive where I can't search, access, and modify the files directly.  I want copies of the files in a standard filesystem.  That said: If there's a way to get Windows Backup to do that to an external drive that will only occasionally be mounted, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

"SyncBack Pro" by 2brightsparks should work great for you as you can set it up to detect each drive and backup, mirror or sync the whole drive to where ever you want and it detects diffent serial IDs for devices so even if the letter doesnt match is can still work. I run this on drives and folders over 1TB in size without issue. Depending on the backup style it can be even faster if you do mirror, after the 1st run it will be faster as it only need to check for changes and backup only whats changed.