# How do I move my Windows 7 installation to a new hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, migration

My OCZ Vertex 3 SSD is dying, and I just got a Kingston HyperX to replace it.

Windows 7 is installed on the 128GB Vertex SSD, and I have a 1.5TB disk for games and media. The SSD only has the OS, MS Office, and Visual Studio.

I just need to migrate the contents of the old SSD to the new SSD. When creating a system image, I do not have the option to only select the C: drive (the SSD); the D: drive (1.5TB) is also included. I guess because many programs are installed in the D: drive, Windows think it's also necessary to include it as part of the image?

My original plan was to just create an image of C: and put it into the D: drive, then boot from DVD and restore the image to the new Kingston HyperX SSD. But now I'm at loss.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone a Hard Disk Content to Another Hard Disk](http://superuser.com/questions/207083/clone-a-hard-disk-content-to-another-hard-disk) and/or [How do I easily copy or clone a Windows boot partition onto a new hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/32164/how-do-i-easily-copy-or-clone-a-windows-boot-partition-onto-a-new-hard-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling the 1.5TB drive in BIOS, then maybe windoze will not see it in the imaging process.

You will obviously have to use a separate (USB?) drive to store the backup, then, swap the SSD drives and restore to the new SSD, then re-enable the 1.5 drive in BIOS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Disabling the D: drive allowed me to create a system image without Windows automatically selecting the drive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install both SSDs into your computer. Download and burn a copy of CloneZilla to a CD/USB. Boot from the CloneZilla media and then clone your Vertex to your HyperX. Remove the Vertex from your computer. All in all, should take 15-30 minutes. You may need to reconfigure your BIOS to boot from the HyperX. Also, if using SATAIII, make sure that you plug both SSDs into the SATAIII controller.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is EaseUS Disk Copy: http://www.easeus.com/disk-copy/

Something else to consider since you are running Windows 7, is to boot directly to a VHD image of your current C: drive.

You can use the [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) utility available from Sysinternals to create a VHD copy of your current C: drive (be sure to run the executable from any other drive EXCEPT the C: drive for it to work properly).

Then you should be able to copy the VHD to your new C: drive and boot from it. Scott Hanselman has a good post about this:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx