# Clone a SATA disk to external USB disk and then back to SATA disk

Tags: clone, disk-utility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to copy or clone boot partition onto new hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/easiest-way-to-copy-or-clone-boot-partition-onto-new-hard-drive)

I need to clone a SATA disk from a Windows 7 computer to an external USB disk. After that I will replace the SATA disk with a new one and copy what is on the USB disk to the new SATA drive.

I have tried to do this with Partition Wizard, but I was not able to make the Windows 7 system boot.

Which software can I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghost, g4l, acronis or any Backup Tools included in the [HirensBootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/).

In some situations the mbr doesn't work after a deploy of the image but you could fix it with a winpe disk or the HBC utility to recovery the mbr.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this tool because it doesn't do dangerous things like messing around with your partition table (like Ghost does):

Drive Snapshot disk imaging
  http://www.drivesnapshot.de/

It can also restore to a different sized disk, and will correct the file system properly (even if the built-in Windows repair tools it attempts to use first fail).  You can also edit (and re-snapshot) the snapshot image (as a virtual hard drive) before restoring it to your new hard drive.