# Move boot partition from TrueCrypt to new drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, truecrypt, migration

I have a laptop with a 500 GB HDD. The C partition takes up almost all the drive. Have 2-3 other small partitions for manufacturer recovery software or system stuff; these came with the laptop.

The C partition is encrypted with TrueCrypt.

I want to migrate everything to a new, 750 GB HDD. I am not concerned about the recovery partition.

It looks like I can't do the [easier options](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive) (gparted, DriveImage XML, EASEUS Disk Copy, etc.) because of TrueCrypt. *If they even work*, I'd end up with a bunch of unallocated space, and all I could do is make another drive, which I don't want. extcv claims to resize TrueCrypt volumes, but its last update is in 2010, and it's only compatible with older TrueCrypt volumes.

Do I have options besides:

1. Set up new OS install on 750 GB HDD, then copy all my data over and set everything back up.
2. Unencrypt 500 GB volume, then use the easier options to copy everything over to the 750 GB volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're moving data to a new drive, what needs to be resized? Why bother unencrypting?

Option 1 sounds correct.

Comment: My C partition occupies almost all of the 500 GB HDD. I'd like for the C partition to occupy almost all of the 750 GB HDD. This cannot happen without changing the partition.

Comment: Changing *what* partition? You have a new 750 GB drive - just copy the files from the 500 GB drive to the 750 GB drive.

The format/structure/size of the old drive doesn't matter (for this process.)

Comment: No, I understand, but I have things on the old HDD that are time-consuming to reconfigure, like some complicated Postgres DBs, and would like to avoid setting everything up again. Was hoping there's a way to clone the partition but make it magically bigger.

Comment: In that case, here's how to make Clonezilla (an awesome disk cloning tool) work with Truecrypt: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/forums/forum/663168/topic/3676076