# Simple replacing system drive under Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive

Can I just copy all files to new drive and replug it as "C". Will it just work?

Comment: No, it won't work. But there are [many solutions](http://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive), you just have to use the search box.

Comment: Why it won't work? :)

Comment: Because hard drive is more than just files. The partition on which your OS is installed has a bootsector that contains instructions for booting that OS. You may also have some specific MBR (Master Boot Record) which serves similar purpose, but for entire drive, not just partition. Without those you'll have your files, but OS won't boot, because it won't know *how* to boot. Backup your drive and restore that backup to a new drive, that's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: As I know, boot sector is identical in all drives formatted for windows. Anyway, it can be fixed with `fdisk /mbr` command or equivalent. Isn't this true? What are other things besides boot sector? In `DOS` times there were two files required to be located in specific place. This is gone now I think.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is possible.

See: [Transfer my system to a replacement hard drive](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_transfer_my_system_to_a_replacement_hard_drive.html).

Edit:
Suggestion: use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), with it you can save an image of your current drive onto your existing new drive. This copies or mirrors the drive completely with data, applications, and settings intact.

Comment: No no, I need not use some "restore from backup" or something. I want just COPY all files from old drive to new one. Is that possible?

Comment: @ Suzan Cioc: yes, the article shows one way to do this. :)