# Can I DOS copy windows vista to a new Hard Drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, 32-bit

I have a Lenovo IBM T60 laptop which I use for running my small business, the current hard drive is only 60gb and i want to copy/clone the entire current 60gb hard drive onto a new 250gb Hard drive, i need it so that i can boot from the 250gb drive. Can i use DOS prompt and if so what is the command? I have a caddy with a a usb connection to the new hard drive for the time being. I purchased the lenovo T60 from a PC shop in East London and they did not provide any VISTA cd's.
many thanks for any help

Comment: DOS is an ancient OS. You have a command line, not DOS. [Related question](http://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive).

Comment: **Just use clonezilla.**

Comment: The manufacturer of the new HDD may provide a free downloadable utility to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you mean cmd.exe (the NT command prompt) rather than DOS.

DOS fell out of use after Win9X, and would need  a tweak to support filenames > 8 characters.

I usually image as it's quicker, or clone, and haven't done a file copy in a while, but you could attach both hard drives to usb, and do

```
robocopy e:\ f:\ /e
```

Perhaps you could even do it from c:\ to  some other internal drive or some usb drive e.g. to e:.  i.e. C is running. I haven't tried it.  You could try that and if that fails then do it from USB to USB booting from your internal/C drive.

robocopy is the successor to xcopy. xcopy was funny with attributes, resetting read only unless told otherwise, and it has no progress bar.  robocopy by default copies all files including hidden and system files and copies attributes, and robocopy has a progress bar, which is also by default(though it's just a per file progress bar).