# Clone OS to another partition as bootable

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, clone

Is there any way to achieve the following:

I want to clone my OS (C: drive) onto another partition. I want this other partition to be boot-able as well.

I read so many articles on the internet about this but none had the answer whether it is possible or not.

Thank you

Comment: Might be possible once you configure the BCD properly but you'll experience problems anyway due to the different drive letter.

Comment: I think this question has been answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive). (What utility can move my Windows boot partition over to another hard drive?) The answers provided are GParted, which you may already be familiar with, or with other software like Drivelmage XML and EASEUS Disk Copy. Edit: Forgot to mention that part of the linked question required it to be bootable, so this should work for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What utility can move my Windows boot partition over to another hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive)

Comment: I am not sure you understood my question. I am not trying to move the OS to another hard drive or partition. I want to keep the existing OS partition and add another bootable partition from the image of the original OS. This way I can have multiple instances of my OS, and at boot time I select which I want to boot into.

Comment: @jadrijan - That require you create an image of that partition.  At which point you can manually update the BCD entries to point to that partition.

Comment: The data that actually tells BIOS which partition to look at to complete boot, is in to boot secotr in the beginning 512 bytes of the drive - If you clone to a new partition, you will need to run windows `bootsect` to reconfigure your bootmanager.