# Cloning partitions of a drive to another

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, clone

I have two drives, one of them has two partitions which are for my Linux distribution whilst the other drive is another drive split up into two other partitions, one partition is for my Windows setup whilst I'd like the other unallocated partition to be occupied by the Linux distro partitions.

My source drive (currently what the distro is installed onto):
[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tlVJ.png)

My target drive (contains my both my Windows setup and unallocated partition):
[Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGLc6.png)

What would be the best program/method of cloning the two partitions from the source drive into the unallocated partition of the target drive via my Windows setup?

Keep in mind that these are two different operating systems so I'm presuming the unallocated partition on the target drive would have to be of a different format which best suits Linux e.g. ext4 rather than NTFS?

Comment: Consider [Reflect Free](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx). It is free for personal use.

Comment: Does it have to be via the Windows Setup? It's much simpler to do both under Linux (if the source and target partitions have the same size, use `dd`, otherwise, use `cp -pr`).

Comment: @sdkks Thanks for that will check it out, have you had any past use of this program? dirkt:  Yes in this specific case I'd prefer to opt for a Windows method.

Comment: Yes for imaging and cloning disks on Windows. Haven't let me down yet. I used to use Symantec Ghost in olden days.

Comment: @sdkks And it allows you to directly clone certain partitions from a drive into another partition on another drive without overwriting the target drive's other partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use clonezilla / gparted from a live-cd of ubuntu, but that's requires a reboot.  If you want a native windows app, there are quite a few hits on google, here's a few from another post [Moving Partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive).

Comment: Would use gparted most of the time but hoping to find a reliable program that I can perform the task with on windows, I'll check a few of those out but never really heard of most of them before so not sure how they work/how reliable they are and how their partition cloning works.