# Moving windows from HDD to SSD (Dualboot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 16)

Tags: windows, boot

I am using Windows-Ubuntu dual boot, but I accidentally installed windows on my HDD drive. I tried to fix the problem manually by copying the windows to a partition in SSD, as well as UEFI partition (100mb) to separate partition in SSD. After fixing grub I got 2 windows launchers, but both of them are pointing to old HDD version of Windows. Is there a way to make the SSD version of windows launchable without reinstalling it?

Comment: Short answer: yes.  Longer answer: that's probably going to take you longer  than just reinstalling, but https://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried EasyBCD to delete some entries?

Comment: Which entries in particular?