# Error code 0xc0000005 while installing windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-installation, segmentation-fault

Following up the story [Moving windows from HDD to SSD (Dualboot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 16)](https://superuser.com/questions/1279405/moving-windows-from-hdd-to-ssd-dualboot-windows-10-ubuntu-16) , I tried to install a fresh copy of Windows 10 to my SSD drive. I took 100gb space from Ubuntu and formatted into NTFS. When I tried to install Windows 10 on it, but got error 0xc0000005 (which is some code for memory error).

Is there any way to get Windows 10 to SSD without actually formatting whole drive? (As I wouldnt want to reinstall Ubuntu again).

Comment: 0xC0000005 is an access violation (segfault). This points to a bug in the installer, but it doesn't rule out other causes. At what point in the installation process does this occur, and do you have any pictures of the error?

Comment: It happens at the start of the installation, right after I have selected the partition. I used the same usb stick with same ISO to install windows 10 on my HDD and it was done without any problems.

Comment: have you tried deleting the NTFS partition, and having the windows installer create/format it?

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work.

Comment: Can you find the setupact.log and setuperr.log on the partition you want to install Windows 10? The temp folder could be created and logs should be here: $Windows.~BT\Sources\Panther. And also device configure related log here: $Windows.~bt\Sources\Rollback\setupapi\setupapi.dev.log. If you can find them, share onto Network drive and post link here.

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer! I have two disks, one HDD with Windows 10 and Reh Hat installed, can work together via grub2, at position 0, and my new SSD, at position 1. When I try to install the Windows 10 ISO in the SSD, I found the installer cannot proceed in any way and I saw the 0xc0000005 error.

After searching it gives me the impression that it is some partition and/or disk error. So, I remove my HDD, make the SSD the only disk(before it is disk 1, now disk 0), and now it works!

I think grub+windows disk manager on disk 0 will affect disk 1, prevent the installation of another Windows 10 in the same machine. In your case, I suggest buying another disk and remove the first one to avoid the grub problem. And before that, I think installing Windows before Ubuntu would be better..