# WIndows In Place Upgrade from 1909 to 21H1

Tags: anytime-upgrade

I have windows 10 Enterprise Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.1801) Installed, It fails to update to Version 21H1. The setup goes until 87 % and closes automatically The exact error thrown is below.

```
PANTHR Exception (code 0xC0000005: ACCESS_VIOLATION) occurred at 0x00007FF9991C103D in C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\SetupPlatform.dll (+00000000003F103D). Minidump attached (165771 bytes) to diagerr.xml and C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\mnd150E.diagerr.mdmp.
```

The hardware used is below notebooks

HP Probook 640 G2

HP Probook 640 G4

HP Elite boook G3.

I have done below steps.

Updated all the drivers for Notebook hardware.

`SFC /scannow`

`DISM restore repair` and found no problems.

Scan Disk no errors found.

I am searching for a solution. To perform an in-place upgrade.

I have tried even using SCCM Server via TS using Upgrade OS Task sequence by that also stops at 96-98 %

and TS quits by throwing below error.

Process completed with exit code 3221225477 it totally stops.

mustafa6177
Pimiento
OP
mustafa6177 Sep 21, 2021 at 11:13 AM

I have already tried removing the McAfee Antivirus we are using, it did not install stuck roll back at same problem. The problem is that i have too many users with 1909 Build,

I need to upgrade them to new version, its not feasible to reinstall all the Notebooks with New Build and transfer the data.

I also tried Using Windows Upgrade Assistant that is also failing give same type of error.

Something went wrong contact Microsoft for help. Here is the error 0xc000005.

I have checked the log in panther folder but did not find any problem.

mustafa6177
Pimiento
OP
mustafa6177 Sep 26, 2021 at 3:04 PM

HI,

I have found solution to my problem. Thanks all for support.

I have to edit the boot partition BCD parameters using BCD edit command. It was looking for boot partitions during windows update which it was unable to locate during setup.

It's working after using BCD edit command.

Comment: Could you run setupdiag and add the output to your answer? Its probably the single best tool for diagnosing windows 10 update issues, and its almost criminal how little known it is https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/setupdiag

Comment: If the update to Version 21H1 fails, perhaps you could go by stages through at least one older version. A good site for downloading older Windows versions is [TechBench by WZT](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php).

Comment: We still need to output of the SetupDiag tool.  However, "I have already tried removing the McAfee Antivirus", did you use the McAfee uninstallation tool? [This is likely a partition layout issue.](https://superuser.com/questions/1279821/error-code-0xc0000005-while-installing-windows-10).  Please provide the partition layout for one of the systems as a screenshot.  Be sure you [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1):

After not initially understanding Mustafa's solution I managed to come to one after finding a discrepancy in the output of bcdedit.exe between computers that were successfully updating and ones that suddenly close with that error (found in event viewer).

Type `bcdedit` in an elevated command prompt to view entries containing boot applications and their configuration data. I found that `{bootmgr}` was completely missing a device field compared to other working computers. My solution was to add it back:

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1`

Answer (score 0):

mustafa6177
Pimiento
OP
mustafa6177 Sep 26, 2021 at 3:04 PM

HI,

I have found solution to my problem. Thanks all for support.

I have to edit the boot partition BCD parameters using BCD edit command. It was looking for boot partitions during windows update which it was unable to locate during setup.

It's working after using BCD edit command.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).